# Density of black cells in rule 110 cellular automata

Tags: co.combinatorics, automata-theory, cellular-automata

Is there a way to compute the limit of the ratio (number of black cells)/(number of white cells), in the [rule 110](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rule110.html) or rule 30 automaton? With initial state = 1 black cell.

Simulation of first 120000 rows of rule 110 shows a quite stable total density of 0.592..., and row-density 0.592...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100876/density-of-black-cells-in-rule-110

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You look at the limit. This means you look at a sequence of numbers r0, r1, r2, ..., rn, ... (or some function). Then, what is n? And, is it clear that the limits really exist?

Comment: I am looking at the limit of the left right-angled-triangle with height n (ie n rows) and base n ( n columns)

Comment: [Simultaneous cross-posting is discouraged](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231). I am closing the post for now, wait a week and if you don't get an answer on [math.se] then flag the post and we will reopen it. Next time please wait a few days before cross-posting your question.